# IIS hosted WCF throws exception when running under domain account

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7, windows-2003-webserver

A little bit too verbose explanation of my problem, but here it goes

I have number of WCF services, most of which are self hosted in windows services on custom ports.

For those self hosted I switched identity under which services are running and got the following error

```
HTTP could not register URL http://+:5731/. 
Your process does not have access rights to this namespace 
(see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).  :     
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
```

In order to solve this under Windows 2003 I used httpcfg to add ACL for that url

```
URL : http://+:5731/
ACL : D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-1644697732-2861104425-3354422928-30323)
```

And after that self hosted ones work just fine

But IIS hosted are not. After I changed Application pool identity it is throwing

```
ServerTooBusyException: The HTTP service located at 
   http://127.0.0.1/Service.svc is too busy
```

I double checked that password entered for Application Pool identity is correct and just in case added permission using httpcfg, which should not be  necessarily

```
URL : http://+:80/
ACL : D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-1644697732-2861104425-3354422928-30323)
```

And I'm still getting `ServerTooBusyException`.

What else should be reconfigured in order to make IIS hosted service to work under specific domain user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it adding domain user to local admin group and doint net stop and net start for w3svc, which is extreme. Working to find more appropriate set of permissions for domain user.